# Parallelised GPU training

Tags: llm, gpt, training

When training/fine-tuning an LLM model it is necessary to have huge GPU resources (VRAM), as such I was wondering if there was a way in Linux to pool GPU resources if I have, say, 5 separate computers running Ubuntu Server. Each computer would basically act as a singular node with its own GPU to form a cluster but is it possible to do this to effectively train an LLM. This would be more cost effective for me personally as I have 5 separate computers with 5 separate GPUs just lying around. Combining these would mean that I could utilise all the VRAM available instead of having to purchase a singular A100 40GB card (which would cost far more).

I suppose that network bandwith limitations may prevent this from ever being possible (since inference requires upwards of 1TB/s VRAM bandwidth alone for a reasonable t/s generation speed).